# jQuery Cycle plugin load issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am using [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) for images slideshow.
On my HTML page I create an unordered list (`ul`) with the class name of `list`

```
<ul class="slide">
 <li>
   <img src="some_photo.png" />
 <li>
 <li>
   <img src="another_photo.png" />
 <li>
<ul>
```

In my HTML page, I load two javascripts in the head section:

```
<head>
...
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/index.js"></script>

...
</head>
```

content of index.js:

```
...
 $(function() {
    $('.slide').cycle({               
        fx:'fade', 
        speed: 500, 
        timeout: 3000,
        pager: '.list',
        activePagerClass: 'active',
        pagerAnchorBuilder:function(index, DOMelement){
          return '<li><a href="#"></a></li>'; 
        }
     });
...
```

The problem that I am having is that when I open the page, I first see the images laid out as if they 
were inside a regular `ul` tag (one on top of the other). Only a few seconds after, it seems that the script transforms them into a slideshow as desired. How can I initiate the `cycle` function before the page loads those images?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change ul-li with a div with same id.
Then you must modify the img class:

```
<img class="slide" ...
```

Finally add this in CSS:

```
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

With this method images will be one BEHIND the others and not one BELOW the others until the script is loaded.